# Separate project files with laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

I was happy with my own mini php framework integrated with composer until laravel 5.1 come out on display. I've been digging laravel for around 2 weeks and was able to create a small blog. More I dig more I get but not all I understand. I guess I've just got the surface. But Laravel is great, thats why I've decided to give up my small framework (so to say).

Past few days I was trying to separate my project files [project, sub-folders as asset, Controllers, template, view] including route.php files but couldn't achieve. **Can anyone help me how to do that? does laravel service->package is the answer?**

One more thing to mention here: Out of the box when I run laravel **it took ~1.6001 seconds to load the welcome page**. Then I tried [php artisan optimize] then it came down to ~0.8000 seconds.

Any kind of help will ventilate me from my asphyxic state.

[I am using laravel in wamp 2.5 - computer hardware: i7 4770k, 8gb ram]

Comment: This question is solved. Developers, kindly delete this question. Thanks

Comment: can you please post the solution as answer?